# Is there a way to find all objects in an array whose fields all objects have the same value postgresql

Tags: java, sql, json, postgresql, pg

Let's see a few objects

```
{
"name: "Test_1",
"attributes": [
    {
        "attribute_name" : "Some_name"
    },
    {
        "attribute_name" : "Some_name_2"
    }
],
"phoneNumber" : "N"
},

{
"name: "Test_2",
"attributes": [
    {
        "attribute_name" : "Some_name"
    },
    {
        "attribute_name" : "Some_name",
        "attribute_phoneNumber": "N1"
    }
],
"phoneNumber" : "N2"
}
```

So, I wanna get objects whose attributes array elements (all of them) have attribute_name  "Some_name"

attributes.attribute_name = Some_name

and as result I wanna get object with Test_2 name because all of attributes elements have this name.

This array 'attributes' saved as jsob in PG, so I tried to use some functions like json_array_elements(...) but it didn't helped
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html

Comment: Please show the code that you tried to use.  Most folks here will not simply do the whole thing for you.

Comment: Is there a specif reason you are looking at the JSON function from the outdated and unsupported 9.5 version?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't show the code with current object I work with. Objects above just for example, but, I can show the query I tried to use.

Comment: It is unclear to me how this data is stored in your table. Is the JSON from your question in a single row (one column)? Or is that spread over multiple rows? What exactly is the result you are after? The rows where the JSON column contains such an attribute? Or a subset of the JSON for each row with only that attribute?

Comment: Select * from test_table ts , json_array_elements(ts.attributes::json) as attributes_obj where attributes_obj ->> 'attribute_name' = 'Some_name'

Comment: All of 1st lvl fields like just name has an own column, attributes - separate column with JSONB type and array saved there like [{attribute_1},{...}] in the cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that these are JSONB fields from 2 records of your table as illustrated in the `the_table` CTE, then select these records for which does not exist an `attributes` array element whose `attribute_name` value is not equal to 'Some_name'. `coalesce` is there for missing `attribute_name` elements.

```sql
with the_table(name, attributes, phonenumber) as 
(
 values
 ('Test_1', '[{"attribute_name" : "Some_name"}, {"attribute_name" : "Some_name_2"}]'::jsonb, 'N'),
 ('Test_2', '[{"attribute_name" : "Some_name"}, {"attribute_name" : "Some_name", "attribute_phoneNumber": "N1"}]', 'N2')
) -- sample data table

select * from the_table where not exists 
(
 select from jsonb_array_elements(attributes) j 
 where coalesce(j->>'attribute_name', '') <> 'Some_name'
);
```

Comment: Oops, 1 `select` too many. Shortened.

Comment: Hello! I tried to use this approach and for objects like

Comment: [
 {
  "name": "Test_3",
  "attributes": [
   {
    "validated": true,
    "test_field": {
     "array_field": [
      {
       "end": "finish"
      }
     ]
    }
   }
  ]
 }
]

Comment: Dont you know there is the way to use same behavior but for that objects that even dont have 'test_field' field. I mean, I want to get only those objects who has this field

Comment: For ex, I use this query: select * from test_table ts  where 
(
 select not exists (
    select * from jsonb_array_elements(ts.attributes::jsonb) j , jsonb_array_elements(j -> 'test_field' -> 'array_field') res
    where coalesce(res ->> 'end', '') != 'finish') 
);  But I've got those objects that doesn't has 'test_field' field at all